# Passing variables between classes

Tags: java, android, object, parameter-passing, getter-setter

My question is how do I pass variables between classes which both the classes `extends Activity`, yes I have 2 main classes

for example, I have a object class that has all the setters and getters which is then put in an `ArrayList<object>`, but when I set the variables in `classA extends Activity` and I want to pass the variables that I set for object class in `classA` so that I can get them in `classB` extends Activity

I tired just doing this in classB

```
ArrayList<object> objArrayList;

objArrayList.get(pos).getName;
```

But all I come back with is a null pointer.

I also did a `Log.d("test", "name: " + objArrayList.get(pos).getName);`

in `classA` it works fine but when I do this in `classB`, I get a nullpointer

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to pass data between activities see this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example"

Comment: Try using static to that variable, sharedpreferences or bundle with string array.

Comment: thx @Allu will check it out now

Comment: @Allu how do I use it as I am fetching the data from a JSON website to an ArrayList, so your saying use SharedPreferences instead of ArrayList? sorry I am not familiar with SharedPreferences is there any other options that which I can use ArrayList instead, cause if I switch to SharedPreferences I have to change everything

Comment: @chiru I have tried making the variables static and putting the data in a String array but still i get a nullpointer

Comment: @mugli the ArrayList is working in Activity A,then you can store ArrayList in SharedPreferences, and retrieve the array-list in Activity B ,and you can use as a array-list as u want here is the simple code to store arraylist.
Retrieving   Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);
//Set the values convert arralist into set
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(arraylist);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();

Comment: check this out...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267826/how-can-i-access-to-an-arraylist-from-another-class/32267999?noredirect=1#comment52415665_32267999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass variables between Activities, use your intent, with which you start your second activity, and the putExtra method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, classB.class);
String name = objArrayList.get(pos).getName;
intent.putExtra("name",name);
```

In your classB you can get this parameter via the getIntent() method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
   String name = extras.getString("name");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Worked out well but just need to add all the other fields in not just "name". thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    In first class,you need to start second activity 

      Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), classB.class);
                i.putExtra("Value1", name);  //name is string value which is need to passed in second activity
                startActivity(i);

        In classB...
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String value = extras.getString("Value1");  
//here as value we get string passed from first activity
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would make this even more understandable to current and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

In your first activity...

```js
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("My_ARRAY_LIST", arrayList);
            startActivity(i);
```

You can put whatever you want to sent String, int, boolean, ArraList etc.
( Object has to be serializable/parceable ) 
and in Second activity you should extract it from intent as,

```js
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> arraList = (ArrayList<String>) i.getSerializableExtra("MY_ARRAY_LIST");
```