# How can I access to an ArrayList from another class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have an `ArrayList` of `Car`:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

that I fill on my `onCreate` method of my `MainActivity.java` with an AsyncTask:

```
new fillCars().execute();
```

What I want it's to use this ArrayList `cars` in other class, named `ModifyCars.java`. My problem it's that after the `AsyncTask` it's executed on the method `onCreate`, in all the class `MainActivity.java` the ArrayList `cars` it's fill and I can use the data inside of it but when I pass it to `ModifyCars.java` the size it's equals to `0`.

The method that I use to pass this `ArrayList` it's to create an empty constructor of the class `MainActivity.java` and create a get method. In the class `ModifyCars.java` I create an object of `MainActivity` and try to use the get method that I created before. Here the code that I used for this purpose:

**In `MainActivity.java`**

```
public MainActivity(){

}

//Here the method onCreate 

public ArrayList<Car> getCars(){
    return cars;
}
```

**In `ModifyCars.java`**

```
MainActivity MA = new MainActivity();
Log.d("prove",Integer.toString(MA.getCars().size())); //Here the size it's 0
```

How can I use my `cars` ArrayList (of course, filled) in my `ModifyCars.java` class? What am I doing wrong?

I search on the Internet but nothing had been useful for me. Any help would really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: never use the new operator on classes that extend Activity

Comment: @MD, why then. Why don't suggest him to let `Car` implement Parcelable ?

Comment: @Error404 : make list static.Simple..!!

Comment: As @Blackbelt said you have more options too. `Parcelable` OR `Serialize ArrayList`

Comment: @Blackbelt Why must not use the new operator on classes that extend Activity? And could you please put a simple example?

Comment: [Take a look](http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development)

Comment: I could. You could use google as well.

Comment: Why this big amount of downvotes? What I did wrong on my question?

Comment: `>100` such a questions already available in SO.

Comment: @MD I know and I promise that I looked for in a lot of them but I couldn't find a solution to my problem (maybe I face them in the wrong way). It's why finally I put a question. And what do you think about the answer of `r j`? Is it better than parcelable or not? (I mean the first option) I'm new at Serializable and Parcelable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the MainActivity that's why you are getting an empty array list there.
A simple solution to that would be making your arryalist static and access it as below,

In MainActivity :

```html
static ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

and in your ModifyCars.java access it as,

```js
    ArrayList<Car> myCars = MainActivity.cars
```

But a standard way to do this would be, sending the array list to the ModifyCars activity while calling it through intent as below,

```js
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ModifyCars.class);
            i.putExtra("CAR_ARRAY_LIST", this.cars);
            startActivity(i);
```

and in ModifyCars activity you should extract it from intent as,

```js
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<Car> myCars = (ArrayList<Car>) i.getSerializableExtra("CAR_ARRAY_LIST");
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now works perfect! I used the first one option because I don't start directly the Intent from `MainActivity`. I use an Intent to send some data from `MainActivity` to other class. And when you click a button in this second one, then it's when `ModifyCars` it's called. Thank you very much again!!

Comment: In that case you should pass the array list from MainActivity to the Second activity and then from Second activity to ModifyCars, because static data is stored in memory which is not a good practice if this data is big as it consumes memory.

Comment: Now it is more clear! Thanks a lot for the extra explanation ;)